# Generate a series of random numbers from a form in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

I have looked around and cannot find a working solution to my problem.

Background -- the intended use is an easy to form for a live rpg group for calculating successes of a downtime action.  By entering numbers into given form fields, the script calculates the total number of "dice" with values between 1 - 10 to be used.  There is also a difficulty threshold that needs to be met on each "roll" of the "dice" to be considered a success.

I am having difficulties generating random numbers using `totalDice` as the size of the array. Once I have that down, I will need to find a way to count and display the total number of random numbers greater than the given difficulty threshold.

For a working example of what I have so far, [see here](http://kdwebmedia.com/successgenerator.html).

I have a `var = totalDice` which provides the size of the random array. The values of the random numbers are 1 - 10.

For example, if `totalDice= 220`, I need 220 random numbers generated between 1 and 10.
Then I have `var = totalDiff` which provides a threshold that I need to compare against the random numbers generated.  I need to find a way to take the array generated and count the number of instances that are `=> totalDiff`.

Example: `totalDice = 220`, `totalDiff = 6`, `totalSuccesses = x`, where `x = the number of elements => 6`.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Walls of text are generally frowned on at SO. Please trim the code down to the relevant sections only.

Comment: edited... my apologies...pared it down to the script only..

Comment: Better, but this is still quite a lot. Less than 10 lines is a good rule of thumb. What are you asking, specifically?

Comment: edited again...cut the code and left it with the bare bones....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Break this into chunks, that's what functions are for.

```
var roll = function() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
};

var getResult = function(difficulty) {
    return roll() >= difficulty;
};

var getAllResults = function(totalDice, difficulty) {
    var arr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < totalDice; i++) {
        arr.push(getResult(difficulty));
    }
    return arr;
};
```

Check:

```
var results = getAllResults(220, 6);
var t = 0;
var f = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    if (results[i]) { 
        t++;
    } else {
        f++;
    }
}
console.log('total rolls', 220);
console.log('total result count (expected 220)', results.length);
console.log('boolean results (expected 220)', t + f);
console.log('successes', t);
console.log('failures', f);
console.log('raw results array', results);
```

**Edit:** If you just want the number of successes, make another function to count them:

```
var getSuccesses = function(results) {
    var successes = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        if (results[i]) { 
            successes++;
        } 
    }
    return successes;
};

//Count successes for 175 die rolls at difficulty 8:
var s = getSuccesses(getAllResults(175, 8));
```

Comment: this looks awesome and I can see the processes going on here.

Comment: now since 220 and 6 are arbitrary numbers that are taken from a calculation and are subject to change every time, would I replace them with the corresponding var?  example change all instances of 220 to totalDice?

Comment: Glad I could help! If this solved your problem, please remember to accept it by clicking the green checkmark.

Comment: Didn't see your last comment. You would call the `getAllResults` function with different parameters, like my `var results = getAllResults(220, 6)` line. Just replace `220, 6` with the correct variables, and that way you can call `getAllResults` over and over again with different parameters. A `getSuccesses` function might help too; I'll edit.

Comment: now not to be pain, but I'm having difficulty seeing where to post the successes to my input/text field - txtTotalSuccesses.

Comment: That's big enough for a whole other question, I'm afraid. You should be able to find the answer on Stack Overflow or [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript), though. I suggest using jQuery, and don't forget to validate your input to make sure it's numeric.

Comment: when i check the console the log shows 0 for all log values...so something is not firing...

Comment: Odd, I get exactly what I expect. Are you using the Chrome JavaScript console? Have a look at this screencap and see if it matches what you're doing: http://i.imgur.com/Ox5ER.jpg

Comment: the only differences are in place of your 220 values i have : totalDice, and in place of your difficulty and 6 value i have : totalDiff....otherwise everything else matches...

Comment: when I do a clean document and run what you have posted it works great... so I'm on the right course... I just need to muddle through the integration to my existing document.

Comment: works phenomenal now.... figured out what I was doing wrong... thanks again so much for all the help today.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but try this:

```
var generateRandomInteger = function(minV, maxV) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (1.0 + maxV - minV) + minV);
}

var generateRandomArray = function(n, minV, maxV) {
    var rv = [];
    for (var i=0; i<n; i++) {
       rv.push(generateRandomInteger(minV, maxV));
    }
    return rv;
};
```

Comment: so if I am correct in my understanding, and I'm probably not.... minV=1 , maxV=10 since thats the range of value, and n=parseInt(totalDice.value) ?